# Sum similar columns

Tags: r, plyr

I would like to sum column that have similar names. I know `plyr` has a numcolwise function, does it have similar for columns?

```
     C1    C1      T1      T1
n1   2     21     12       12
n2   12    12     34       45


      C1   T1
n1    23   24
n2    22   79
```

Comment: Value at `n2` , `C1` should be 24 I believe.

Comment: How do you have columns with the same name?

Answer (score 3):

I would do it using `sapply`, looping over `unique` names of `df` and gathering all the columns with similar names and taking row-wise sum of them.

```
sapply(unique(names(df)), function(x) rowSums(df[names(df) %in% x]))

#   C1 T1
#n1 23 24
#n2 24 79
```

---

Another option is to transpose the dataframe and use `rownames` as grouping variable and sum columns by group using `rowsum`.

```
rowsum(t(df), rownames(t(df)))

#   n1 n2
#C1 23 24
#T1 24 79
```

Comment: If the dataframe contained characters then you will be unable to transpose as that will change the class of the numeric columns to characters

Comment: @Onyambu Based on the data provided by OP, I am assuming that they have numeric data and you can not sum characters anyway, so that would not make any sense then.

Comment: Well but it is possible to have some columns to be numeric..and others character. Its okay though...

Comment: `data.frame(lapply(split(as.list(dat),names(dat)),Reduce,f="+"))`.. May be you can include the condition of if character...else...I guess

Comment: I think it is better to transpose once `df1 <- t(df)` and then call it in `rowsum`

Comment: @akrun Yes, definitely that would be better instead of calling `t`ranspose twice.